# How to solve for y(3) if y(1) is known for the given differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The given differential equation is $x {dy \over dx} = y( \ln y - \ln x +1)$

The initial condition is y(1)=3. Need to find y(3).

Comment: You can solve this explicitly. Set $u = \ln(y)$.

Comment: Let $u=\dfrac{y}{x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=\dfrac{y}{x}$ so given differential equation is
\begin{eqnarray}
x {dy \over dx} &=& y( \ln y - \ln x +1)\\
u'x+u&=&u(\ln u+1)\\
\dfrac{du}{u\ln u} &=&\dfrac{dx}{x}\\
\int\dfrac{du}{u\ln u} &=&\int\dfrac{dx}{x}\\
\ln\ln u&=&\ln x+\ln C\\
y&=&x3^{x}\\
y(3)&=&81
\end{eqnarray}